# How do you create optional arguments in php?

Tags: php

In the PHP manual, to show the syntax for functions with optional parameters, they use brackets around each set of dependent optional parameter. For example, for the [`date()`](https://php.net/date) function, the manual reads:

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

Where `$timestamp` is an optional parameter, and when left blank it defaults to the [`time()`](https://php.net/time) function's return value.

How do you go about creating optional parameters like this when defining a custom function in PHP?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Much like the manual, use an equals (`=`) sign in your definition of the parameters:

```
function dosomething($var1, $var2, $var3 = 'somevalue'){
    // Rest of function here...
}
```

Comment: `function dosomething($var1, $var2, $optionalValue = null)` I found this better option.

Comment: setting the parameter to null would act like an optional argument. Setting the parameter to a value like this answer is doing is more like a default value than an 'optional' value.

Answer (score 56):

> The default value of the argument must be a constant expression. It can't be a variable or a function call.

If you need this functionality however:

```
function foo($foo, $bar = false)
{
    if(!$bar)
    {
        $bar = $foo;
    }
}
```

Assuming `$bar` isn't expected to be a boolean of course.

Comment: however, this will evaluate if 0 or "false" was passed to $bar.

Comment: @DooMMasteR, here, you mean `$bar === false` - this is an action that should be done when `$bar` has defaulted to `false`.  This will avoid incorrect action if `0` is passed in, so it does work - UNLESS a boolean is needed. As Kzqai said, a more general solution is to use `$bar = null`, because that can also be used when the values of $bar are boolean.  The test then becomes  `if (is_null($bar))` or `if ($bar === null)`.

Answer (score 24):

Some notes that I also found useful:

- Keep your default values on the right side.

  ```
  function whatever($var1, $var2, $var3="constant", $var4="another")
  ```
- The default value of the argument must be a constant expression. It can't be a variable or a function call.

Answer (score 15):

Give the optional argument a default value.

```
function date ($format, $timestamp='') {
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The date function would be defined something like this:

```
function date($format, $timestamp = null)
{
    if ($timestamp === null) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }

    // Format the timestamp according to $format
}
```

Usually, you would put the default value like this:

```
function foo($required, $optional = 42)
{
    // This function can be passed one or more arguments
}
```

However, only *literals* are valid default arguments, which is why I used `null` as default argument in the first example, **not** `$timestamp = time()`, and combined it with a null check. Literals include arrays (`array()` or `[]`), booleans, numbers, strings, and `null`.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't know how many attributes need to be processed, you can use the variadic argument list token(`...`) introduced in PHP 5.6 ([see full documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)).

Syntax:

```
function <functionName> ([<type> ]...<$paramName>) {}
```

For example:

```
function someVariadricFunc(...$arguments) {
  foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
    // do some stuff with $arg...
  }
}

someVariadricFunc();           // an empty array going to be passed
someVariadricFunc('apple');    // provides a one-element array
someVariadricFunc('apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana');
```

As you can see, this token basically turns all parameters to an array, which you can process in any way you like.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with 7.1 there is a type hinting for nullable parameters

```
function func(?Object $object) {}
```

It will work for these cases:

```
func(null); //as nullable parameter
func(new Object());  // as parameter of declared  type
```

But for optional value signature should look like.

```
function func(Object $object = null) {} // In case of objects
function func(?Object $object = null) {} // or the same with nullable parameter

function func(string $object = '') {} // In case of scalar type - string, with string value as default value
function func(string $object = null) {} // In case of scalar type - string, with null as default value
function func(?string $object = '') {} // or the same with nullable parameter

function func(int $object = 0) {} // In case of scalar type - integer, with integer value as default value
function func(int $object = null) {} // In case of scalar type - integer, with null as default value
function func(?int $object = 0) {} // or the same with nullable parameter
```

than it can be invoked as

```
func(); // as optional parameter
func(null); // as nullable parameter
func(new Object()); // as parameter of declared type
```

Comment: See also [What is a Nullable Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372)