# How do I add optional arguments to my function?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create optional arguments in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/how-do-you-create-optional-arguments-in-php)

I built a function with 1 argument. That function is called numerous places on many, many pages on my site. I just decided that I need another parameter for this function.

In order to avoid "Warning: Missing argument" errors, is there any way to add a second argument with a bit of logic that tests the presence of a second argument in the calling command?

I do not want to go back through my entire website and try to catch and update every function call merely to throw a null value on it in order to void the error messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a [default value](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) for your arguments:

```
function foo($arg1, $optional_arg2 = NULL)
{
  // ...
}
```

`$optional_arg2 = NULL` specifies that if not given when the function is called, `$optional_arg2` will be `NULL`. The default value of an argument can be a scalar value (string, number or boolean), an array, or `NULL`, but it cannot be a variable, class member or function call.

Comment: Ohhhh. I completely misunderstood the purpose for the argumnent default value.

Comment: Ohhhh. I completely misunderstood the purpose for the argumnent default value.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for clearing up the concept for me Daniel!!

Comment: just tested it and it worked just as I need it too. After all these years of php coding I never really knew about that feature...I guess you just learn something new every day. Thanks again Daniel and hsz.

Comment: @Dr. DOT, please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can define default the second argument value.

```
function functionName( $first, $second = false ) { ... }
```

And now if you left the second argument it will have `false` value. In the next case you call

```
functionName("test", true);
```

and overwrite default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@params array $options

    function test($options) {
       $option1 = $options['option1'];
       ...
    }
```