# How to call a type hinted php function without parameter

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

I have a php function:

```
function myFunc(MyClass inst) {
    // ...
}
```

Sometimes, when I call this function, I dont want to pass any arguments, but this doesn't work:

```
myFunc(null);
```

The error message is:

```
... must be an instance of MyClass , null given
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create optional arguments in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/how-do-you-create-optional-arguments-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your function's arguments **optional**, by providing default values. So instead of

```
function myFunc(MyClass inst)
```

it should be

```
function myFunc(MyClass inst=null)
```

See docs http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

Just put the default initializer like so:

```
function myFunc(MyClass inst=null) {
    // ...
}
```

Then if you don't want to pass params, call it without ones :D