# How to make function argument optional in PHP?

Tags: php, function, argument-passing, optional-parameters, default-arguments

Suppose following is my function definition:

```
public function addPhotoFeed($val)
{
-----------------------------
------------------------------
-----------------------------
}
```

In above function `$val` is an array that is passed as an argument to the same.

Now I want to call the above function when I don't pass any argument. So how should I call it?

Comment: Link to the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).... reading the docs can be very, very useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create optional arguments in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/how-do-you-create-optional-arguments-in-php)

Comment: ... and searching Stack Overflow prior to asking a question can also be very, very useful `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign the parameter to null, so like this.

```
public function addPhotoFeed($val = null)
{
 //TODO
}
```

You will be able to call the function with or without parameters

```
addPhotoFeed();
addPhotoFeed("Something");
```

If you don't want the function to do anything when its called with a null parameter, then you could add a condition inside the function, something like this.

```
public function addPhotoFeed($val = null)
{
   if($vall == null)
     // Do nothing
   else
     // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default value:

```
public function addPhotoFeed($val = array())
```