# call a function by omitting function argument

Tags: php

```
function givemeposts($user, $pos){
$sql = "select * from posts where user ='" . $user . "' and pos = '" . $pos . "' order by inde";    
...

givemeposts('public', 'home01'); // this works as usual
```

Now I nedd to call the above function, but without `$pos` param, i.e. whatever `$pos` value is.

Something like:

```
givemeposts('public', whatever);
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: You can make the argument optional, `function givemeposts($user, $pos = ''){` for example.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/how-do-you-create-optional-arguments-in-php)

Comment: @Ollaw, sql injection using SELECT statement !? Could you give me an example, pls.

Comment: @Qirel, so, how can I call the function WHATEVER is in the `pos` column? The column is not empty!

Comment: @bonaca It's always a bad practice put variables directly inside a query. I recommend you to use mysqli or PDO. 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use default parameter :

```
function givemepost( $user , $pos=NULL ){
    if($pos==NULL){
        //some code
    }lese{
         $sql = "select * from posts where user ='" . $user . "' and pos = '" . $pos . "' order by inde";    
    }
}
```

This way you can call the function with one paramter, and set what the function have to do, inside the if branch.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can set [default values for arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.
>
> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

If you do this, the default value for $pos will be **''** (an empty string):

```
function givemeposts($user, $pos = ''){
```

Or you can something else than an empty string, whatever value you want:

```
function givemeposts($user, $pos = 'SomeValue'){
```

Then you can simply call your function like this:

```
givemeposts($user);
```

Comment: So, how can I call the function WHATEVER is in the `pos` column? The column is not empty!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function givemeposts($user, $pos = '')
{
    if(!empty($pos)) {
        $pos = "AND pos = '" . $pos . "'";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user ='" . $user . "' $pos ORDER BY inde";

}

givemeposts('public');
```