# php make set_error_handler return an error string

Tags: php

I need to put a contents of 'PHP Warning' into a variable. For these purposes I got the following code (set_error_handler() in a php class):

```
$data = '';
set_error_handler( function() use ($this, &$data) { $data = $this->my_error_handler(); return $data; } );
//some code that throws Warning
restore_error_handler();

function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr) {
    return $errstr;
}
```

But I get the following 500 error: `Type error: Too few arguments to function my_error_handler(), 0 passed`. 
If I replace a callable above with a string, code works without a 500 error, but  I cannot pass a variable in it and return it with a contents of warning thrown. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: To work around the `Too few arguments` you could provide default values for the arguments and thus make them "optional" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/how-do-you-create-optional-arguments-in-php)

Comment: Try to throw exception and save the exception message into a variable.